# How can I retrieve items and their details from the shell:AppsFolder virtual folder using c#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to get all the items from the FOLDERID_AppsFolder, which you can access by running `explorer.exe shell:appsFolder` command, and their details, specifically the AppUserModelID.

I can get the name of the items using the code below but I am not sure how to get the AppUserModelID. Can I get this value somehow?

```
IShellItem appsFolder;
string str;
var res = ShellItemUtilities.SHGetKnownFolderItem(ShellItemUtilities.FOLDERID_AppsFolder,
              0, IntPtr.Zero, typeof(IShellItem).GUID, out appsFolder);
if (res < 0) return;

try
{
    var pidl = default(PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE);
    foreach (var app in appsFolder.Enumerate())
    {                    
        try
        {
            recyleBin.GetDisplayName(2, out ptr);
            // Get the actual name of the item
            str = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ptr);
        }
        finally
        {   
            if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ptr);
                ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
        }
    }
}
...
```

Perhaps the [`IShellItem::GetAttributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellitem-getattributes) method is what I need but it can only retrieve the attribute that I specify through the `sfgaoMask` parameter and the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/sfgao) regarding the values for this parameter does not include anything related to the AppUserModelID.

And for reference, this is what the apps folder looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you hear the crickets chirping?

I was eventually able to find a solution to this problem when I stumbled upon the [Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Shell](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Shell/) nuget package which wraps all the shell commands I needed so that I don't have to P/Ivoke them. The code now becomes:

```
// GUID taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/knownfolderid
var FODLERID_AppsFolder = new Guid("{1e87508d-89c2-42f0-8a7e-645a0f50ca58}");
ShellObject appsFolder = (ShellObject)KnownFolderHelper.FromKnownFolderId(FODLERID_AppsFolder);

foreach (var app in (IKnownFolder)appsFolder)
{
    string name = app.Name;
    // The ParsingName property is the AppUserModelID
    string appUserModelID = app.ParsingName; // or app.Properties.System.AppUserModel.ID
    ImageSource icon =  app.Thumbnail.MediumBitmapSource;
}
```

The ShellObject object actually contains a whole lot more proeprties available through it's Properties.System props.

In case you are wondering why I am casting the appsFolder to a `ShellObject` at instantiation only to cast it back to an `IKnownFolder` when enumerating, that's because the API code pack actually comes with a `ShellObjectWatcher` which takes a `ShellObject` and monitors it for changes. If a new app is installed and it is listed in this virtual folder, the watcher can be used to monitor for this:

```
ShellObjectWatcher sow = new ShellObjectWatcher(appFolder, false);
sow.AllEvents += (s, e) => DoWhatever();
sow.Start();
```